# Scala shapeless polymorphic value function for numeric types

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

I need to write a function that will receive a function that will transform a `List[T]` into a `T`. For example, summing the elements of the list.

My first try was to use shapeless polymorphic functions as:

```
object sumPoly extends (List ~> Option) = {
  def apply[T: Numeric](list: List[T]): Option = Some(list.sum)
}
```

but I get an error because shapeless expect the function to be `def apply[T](...)`

The function that receives the function above would look like:

```
def test(list: List[Any], f: (List ~> Option)) = {
  val intTypeCase = TypeCase[List[Int]]
  val doubleTypeCase = TypeCase[List[Double]]
  val longTypeCase = TypeCase[List[Long]]
  list match {
    intTypeCase(l) => f(l)
    doubleTypeCase(l) => f(l)
    longTypeCase(l) => f(l)
    // more type matchings here
  }
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do?

### EDIT

After some searches I found that it is possible to do the following:

```
object sumPoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseListInt = at[List[Int]](x => x.sum)
  implicit def caseListDouble = at[List[Double]](x => x.sum)
  // more type matchings here
}
```

and calling `sumPoly(List(1, 1, 1))` correctly returns `3`. But if I define the `test` function as:

```
def test(list: List[Any], f: Poly1) = {
  val intTypeCase = TypeCase[List[Int]]
  val doubleTypeCase = TypeCase[List[Double]]
  val longTypeCase = TypeCase[List[Long]]
  list match {
    intTypeCase(l) => f(l)
    doubleTypeCase(l) => f(l)
    longTypeCase(l) => f(l)
    // more type matchings here
  }
  ...
}
```

and pass the `sumPoly` function, I get the errors like this for each type I defined in the `test` function: `could not find implicit value for parameter cse: shapeless.poly.Case[f.type,shapeless.::[List[Int],shapeless.HNil]]`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why a function `List[T] => T` implemented in terms of `sum`, or more generally `foldLeft/Right` isn't suitable for this?

Comment: @MilesSabin I'm still learning Scala, I looked up foldLeft/Right and it seems that function will not help if I understand your comment correctly. The function `f` that `test` receives should perform a sum, min, max, product, etc operation on the list. The method `test` would be a part of a generic class from which concrete classes would be derived, one class per operation. Basically, I want to reduce the code repetition (type match cases) by passing the function `f` instead of repeating the type matching in each of the concrete classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at shapeless' code I found I can do the following:

```
object sumPoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseList[T: Numeric] = at[List[T]] { x => x.sum }
}
```

and then the function which will receive the `Poly1` must have the following definition:

```
def test(list: List[Any], f: Poly1) 
        (implicit li : f.Case[List[Int]], 
                  ld : f.Case[List[Double]], 
                  ll : f.Case[List[Long]])= {

  val intTypeCase = TypeCase[List[Int]]
  val doubleTypeCase = TypeCase[List[Double]]
  val longTypeCase = TypeCase[List[Long]]
  list match {
    intTypeCase(l) => f(l)
    doubleTypeCase(l) => f(l)
    longTypeCase(l) => f(l)
    // more type matchings here
  }
  ...
}
```

this way, I can create different `Poly1` functions like `sum`, `prod`, `min`, `max` that convert `List[T]` into a `T` where `T` is numeric.

The design might seem contrived, but I am interop-ing with Java. More specifically, with Hadoop libraries written in Java.